# Why event not working when MainPage() changed to NavigationPage()?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I have this little mobile app uses `XZing.Net` that scans QR code and it works just fine. Now I am required instead of showing the result in the same page, it must be on another page.

Now I have to change my code to be able to navigate through pages.

**App.xaml.cs**

from:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new MainPage();
}
```

To:

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

from:

```
public void Handle_OnScanResult(Result result)
{
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
   {
       await DisplayAlert("Scanned result", result.Text, "OK");
   });
}
```

To:

```
public void Handle_OnScanResult(Result result)
{
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
   {
       await Navigation.PushAsync(new ScannedResult());  
   });
}
```

And my ScannedResult.xaml.cs

```
public ScannedResult()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void LoadResult(string result)
{
    LblScannedResult.Text = "rverfcwefcdfcfvcerfgcfcdfcsf";
}
```

I noticed that by changing `MainPage = new MainPage();` to `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())`; the scanner didnt work.

Here is the method that handles when the scan is successful:

```
public void Handle_OnScanResult(Result result)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
       //await Navigation.PushAsync(new ScannedResult()); // it should navigate to another page when the scan is successful.
       await DisplayAlert("Scanned result", result.Text, "OK");
    });
}
```

Any suggestion?
PS: And how to pass the result to another page?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the result when you navigate to ScannedResult page:

```
public void Handle_OnScanResult(Result result)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ScannedResult(result));
    });
}
```

And in your ScannedResult page, create a new construction method with parameter result. Then you can get the scan result and use it in ScannedResult page:

```
public partial class ScannedResult : ContentPage
{
    public ScannedResult()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ScannedResult(string result)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var scanResult = result;

        LblScannedResult.Text = result;
    }
}
```